# Can '%' in a pattern-rule match an EMPTY string, in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro):

> For example, `%.c` as a pattern matches any file name that ends in
>   `.c`.  `s.%.c` as a pattern matches any file name that starts with `s.`,
>   ends in `.c` and is at least five characters long.  (There **must be at
>   least one character to match the `%`.**)  The substring that the `%`
>   matches is called the "stem".

```make
D/all:

al%l;
    echo '$@'
```

Running, I get:

```console
echo 'D/all'
D/all
```

Given the quote above:

> There must be at least one character to match the `%`.

How does the target `all` match the pattern `al%l` (Which clearly implies that `%` matches an **empty** string).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that what the manual is really trying to say there is that "there must **be** a stem". Which there is there. The stem is `D/`. You can see that by adding `echo '$*'` to the `al%l` target.

Comment: If anything, it shows that Make is not pedantic enough, when checking if `%` matched any non-empty string, as it allows any "stem" to account for this match. So, it sure explains "how did it happen". But should it be like that? Was this intentional? I doubt it.

Comment: It is either a bug (i.e. your comment about not pedantic enough) or it is intentional and the manual isn't explicit enough. In either case an email to the gnu-make mailing list and/or a bug filed against the project is likely to result in a better outcome then just posting here.